# javascript regex (regular expression)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate phone numbers. it must have a "+" sign followed by [0-9].

I need something like /^ + . [0-9]*$/

I don't know how to implement the "+" sign and how to have it validate only once. 
Concerning the length It does not matter for my purpose.

Comment: The `+` is part of the regex syntax, you should escape it...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the line below:

```
str.match(/^\+[0-9]+$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
/^\+[0-9]+$/
```

and test it using `test()` like this -

```
> /^\+[0-9]+$/.test("+9009900")
true
```